# Backup statement in sql 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In SQL 2012 i have the following query:
"

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50) -- database name  
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256) -- path for backup files  
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256) -- filename for backup  
DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(20) -- used for file name
```

-- specify database backup directory

```
SET @path = 'D:\BACKUP\'
```

-- specify filename format

```
SET @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112) 
--SELECT @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112) + REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),108),':','')



DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb')  -- exclude these databases

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       SET @fileName = @path + @name + '_' + @fileDate + '.BAK'  
       BACKUP DATABASE @name TO DISK = @fileName --with differential
       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor "
```

This query made the backup for databases, but if i run it again the new backup is placed in the same file. How can i do, that the new backup to be placed in a new .bak file?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using

```
SET @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112)
```

It means that you get only the Date portion of the current date.
Use a format that adds hour and minute.

```
SET @fileDate = REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),126),":",""),"-","")
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are trying to create backup of DB , i would recommend you using [Olla Hagrens Scripts](http://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html). They work for us and i think they are quite popular as well. He has loads of other utilites which will help you if you dont already have them.

He has taken care of all the Date Time formatting as well. You can have a look at his scripts for the answer you are after

Answer (score 0):

You can make your @filedate by using below SQL Script

`

```
Declare @TimeStp as varchar(14) 
Declare @filedate as varchar(255) 
Select @TimeStp=Ltrim(str(DATEPART(yyyy, Getdate())))
Select @TimeStp=@TimeStp+right('0'+Ltrim(str(DATEPART(mm, Getdate()))),2)
Select @TimeStp=@TimeStp+right('0'+Ltrim(str(DATEPART(dd, Getdate()))),2)
Select @TimeStp=@TimeStp+right('0'+Ltrim(str(DATEPART(hh, Getdate()))),2)
Select @TimeStp=@TimeStp+right('0'+Ltrim(str(DATEPART(mi, Getdate()))),2)
Select @TimeStp=@TimeStp+right('0'+Ltrim(str(DATEPART(ss, Getdate()))),2)
Select @filedate = @TimeStp
```

`